# Excel opens in protected view only at second time

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing a strange issue with my excel. Excel contains large macro codes. Recently I have added some more macros to that.

This excel will be distributed to end users through web page, so users can download their own file.

When user downloaded and open in their own system there is no issues at first time. User edits the content and saving it.

At second time when reopening the file user getting error message 
**"protected view office has detected a problem with this file vba macro"**

[image]

After that the file is normal there is no issue with excel. I am facing this issue 
 only at second time not more than that.

I want to control this issue with VBA macro code. I can't change settings in users PC

Comment: You can't change this with code.  It would defeat the very purpose of Protected Mode.  It would be like an anti-virus program allowing a virus to turn it off.

Comment: Okay understood, any idea why this error occurs

Comment: Not without seeing the full contents of the file and the security settings on the PC I'm afraid.  Did this occur when you made your recent changes?  If so, what are these changes?  Have you signed the file?

Comment: Could it be that you are using different versions of Excel?

Comment: This may have something to do with *where* the user saves the file. Check in the Trust Center on that machine to see what *folders* are set to be automatically trusted. See if saving the file after downloading it to a *trusted folder* makes a difference?